# processDebugResources FAILED after changing icon launcher

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I change launcher icon in this address:

```
Projects\nameproject\android\app\src\main\res
```

And then linked them by this command:

```
npx react-native link
```

after re-building project by this command:

```
react-native run-android
```

I am getting following error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with
Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:comman
d_line_warnings
108 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 103 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\TORANJ\Desktop\Projects\insta\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_
manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher
_round (aka com.insta:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development envi
ronment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.htm
l#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8
081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\TORANJ\Desktop\Projects\insta\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_
manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher
_round (aka com.insta:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.
```

I ran `gradlew clean` but issue is persisting:

Does anybody have any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue here, if you got a workaround, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue. It is because react-native android app icons run in round shaped. It shows build/ processDebugResources failed because we didn't add circle shaped app icon in **res** folder.

First, after creating a fresh project, look in the **android/app/src/main/res** folder, you will find **ic_launcher** & **ic_launcher_round**, right?

So, I suggest you to go [Launcher icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) to make two shaped icons (circle and square), paste them in icon folders with same name(ic_launcher & ic_launcher_round) and build the project.

You will find that app icon is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy **ic_launcher** and past it to same folder as **ic_launcher_round**. for example in **mipmap-hdpi** folder i just have an ic_launcher file and I manually copy and paste this, then `run cd android && ./gradlew clean` and run `npx react-native link` in root folder again, then rebuild the project again with `npx react-native run-android` command.